# HttpListenerResponse OutputStream.Write extremely slow on my server

Tags: c#, linux, http, mono, webserver

I wanted to set up a very basic webserver in C# on my server (Linux version 2.6.32-5-vserver-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48).
The server is in my my city and near zero overhead functionality like displaying 7 lines of html via Apache2 or Tomcat 8 takes ~15ms (DNS 1ms, Connecting 4ms, Sending 1ms, Waiting 6ms, Receiving 4ms).
When running my minimal c# webserver on that server the Receiving phase lasts 60ms!
I tried it out on my local computer in .net framework and mono as well and it always takes just a single millisecond at worst.
By testing a bit I found out that if I don't send any data via context.Response.OutputStream.Write(...) it's even faster than Apache2 or Tomcat, with Receiving going down to 0ms!
Sending headers doesn't make it slower and works fine.
Mono 3.0.6 is running on the server and I used 3.0.6 on my Windows PC for testing.
It boils down to the question:
**Why is OutputStream.Write(...) so slow on my server and how do I fix it?**

Here is the C# code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.HttpListener listener = new System.Net.HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://domain.tld:7777/");
        //listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:7777/");
        //listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:7777/");
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            System.Net.HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ProcessRequest(context); });
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessRequest(System.Net.HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        System.Net.HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/html";
        byte[] bytes = GetBytes("Testtext");
        response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); // this line makes the request 60ms slower!
        context.Response.Headers.Add("headerName", "This is the headervalue");
        response.Close();
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you move `Headers.add()` before `OutputStream.Write()`?

Comment: I shouldn't have put it here I guess: It has zero impact on performance whether I use it at all. I merely wanted to emphasize that "sending custom strings" is fine if I do it via header.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution, or rather workaround:
If I use

```
response.Close(bytes, bool); // doesn't matter whether boolean is true or false
```

and don't write to the Stream at all it's blazingly fast. Fine with me but I still don't get it.

Comment: If I could upvote you 50 times for this one I would. No idea what's going on  in there, but saw the exact same issue. In Chrome it's in the "Content Download" section of the response - 350ms to handle 2 characters. When I swapped to your method, worked like a charm.

Comment: Turns out this is an issue with the ContentLength64 header; if you set it, things work nicely, like this: Response.ContentLength64 += bytes.Length;

Comment: Is it possible to use your solution multiple times? I mean adding the size of the next byte array to ContentLength64 and then sending it via OutputStream more than once.

Comment: Honestly not sure - my particular need doesn't hit that.